# Git created a new branch from an active branch and unable to push due to a fast forward error

Tags: git

I created a branch called `feature 2` from an existing branch called `feature 1`.

Other developers are still pushing commits to `feature 1`.

I am working on a parallel feature in the branch `feature 2`.

I cannot push changes in my branch feature 2 to the remote because of an a non fast forward error.

> ! [rejected]        feature1 -> feature1 (non-fast-forward) hint:
>   Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
>   hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote
>   changes hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again. hint: See
>   the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

How do I resolve this:

Should I switch branches locally to `feature 1` and pull those changes.

And then switch back to `feature 2` and then push to the remote.

Or do i need to rebase? (I'm not sure what this actually does). Which command should I use?

Comment: _"Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again"_

Comment: You claim you're trying to push `feature 2` but the error is about `feature 1`. Have you actually checked out your new branch, or did you just create it but stay on `feature 1`?